# Update main branch with changes in a branch that start from a commit before main

Tags: git

I have a `main` branch pushed. Then I created a branch `B` from an old commit of `main` and now I want `main` to be the same as the `B` branch.

My situation:

```
* B branch
|
*
|
*  * C branch
|  |
*  * main
|  |
*  * [commit-x]
| /
*
|
```

And I would like to have this:

```
* main
|
*
|
*  * C branch
|  |
*  * 
|  |
*  * [commit-x]
| /
*
|
```

I tried merging `B` in `main` but doing so I get also some commits from main (example `commit-x`) that I don't want:

I need help.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are other people using this repo, and if so, are you sure you want to do this? Rewriting shared branches such as `main` is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, and I know but is there another solution?

Comment: I added another option showing how to revert commits on `main` you don't want anymore. Note the first option has a cleaner history, but that can mess up other users that are already working off of the latest `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I question whether you want to do this, since generally rewriting shared branches such as `main` is frowned upon. That being said, to answer your question, this is as simple as changing `main` to point to `B`. (Note `B` could be a branch name or a commit ID hash.)

```
git switch main
git reset --hard B
git push --force-with-lease
```

This works because branches are just "bookmarks" or "pointers" to a commit ID. The `reset` command is used to change what commit a branch points to.

If you don't wish to *rewrite* the `main` branch, another option would be to `revert` the commits on `main` that you don't want. So you could do this instead:

```
git switch main
git revert commit-X # this is the commit ID you wish to undo.
git merge B
```

Now `commit-X` will still be in the history but the changes will be gone.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what the last command does. Is it necessary?

Comment: I changed it to make it simpler. The effect is the same and easier to understand now, I think.

Comment: Oh yeah, in that case I don't need to do the cherry pick, I can simply merge B in main, am I right? (or rebase B on main)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Merge B into main, or first rebase B onto main and then merge it into main.

Comment: If you rebase B onto main before merging it in, the end result would be the same as the previous cherry-pick command I had which basically did it in one line, but was far more complicated to read.